# CSS not appearing on site

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, stylesheet

After looking around the internet I have not been able to figure out why my css is not working on my webpage. Also my title does not appear on the page if anyone knows why that happens that would be nice as well.

Here is my webpage

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
 <head>
  <title> Basic3 </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="/jmurphy9/111/css/basic.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2><p> This is the Basic3 Page</p></h2>
  <img src="/jmurphy9/111/images/apollo15.jpg" alt="The Apollo 15 spacecraft"   height="200">   
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my style sheet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style type= "css">
 body { background-color: #4BBEDB;
        margin-left: 6%; }
</style>
</html>
```

Please help! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet is wrong, it contains HTML, it should only be:

```
body { background-color: #4BBEDB;
    margin-left: 6%; }
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file should contain just CSS. Take all the HTML out.

You also need to fix your `<link>` tag. The MIME type for CSS is `text/css`, not `css`. Browsers won't download stylesheets in unknown stylesheet languages.